# Numerical integration - Gauss quadrature rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

How do we numerically integrate a rapidly decaying exponential function? A simple Gauss quadrature which is based on approximating the function by polynomial, I think will not work, since rapidly decaying exponential function will require more terms in the series. Is there a series approximation for the function?

Comment: Did you try the variants of the basic Gauss quadrature like Gauss–Laguerre quadrature and Gauss–Hermite quadrature?

Comment: I haven't applied them yet but aren't they of different form? Will they work for a rapidly decaying function? I have the integral of the form $$\int f(x)e^{-kx}$$, where k lies in the range of [10,50]

Comment: @vijay: is $f(x)$ smooth, or does it have singular behavior (e.g. at the left endpoint)?

Comment: @J.M. f(x) is smooth. Ok, I think I will be more clear here. The actual integration to be done goes like this,$$\int (\int f(v) e^{-kvx}dv \int g(v) e^{-kvx}dv)dx$$. Integrands with $f(v)$ & $g(v)$ can only be numerically evaluated. They have 10th order polynominal in $v$ in the denominator.

Comment: ...and how sure are you that the denominator polynomial has no zeroes within the interval of integration?

Comment: I have plotted the function for $x=0$ (the denominator has no $x$ anyway). Both $f(v)$ & $g(v)$ decays for $v>2$. And the functions are smooth.

Comment: I'm able integrate using simpson's rule. But the number of function evaluation is more.

Answer (score 1):

Variable substitution to make $k=1$, and use [Gauss-Laguerre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature). For more advanced method, the [double exponential transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/which-one-result-in-maths-has-surprised-you-the-most/2977#2977) maybe relevant.

Comment: I would say that vanilla DE is overkill here if the integrand already has a decaying exponential factor; however, Mori and Takahasi do have a modified version suitable for integrands with decaying exponentials; see their paper for details. Otherwise, Gauss-Laguerre *ought to* work well here, unless the $f(x)$ in $f(x)\exp(-kx)$ has wonky behavior on its own. The problem with Gauss-Laguerre is that it doesn't admit a natural error estimate; one has to usually compare the results for $n$ nodes and $n+1$ nodes.