# Deepest theorems with simplest proofs

Tags: soft-question, elementary-number-theory, intuition

Which are the deepest theorems with the most elementary proofs?
I give two examples:
i) [Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function)
ii) Proof that the halting problem is undecidable using diagonalization

Comment: This should be community wiki, I think.

Comment: Proving the incompleteness theorems requires a little more than just diagonalization.

Comment: Something like this got asked in MO IIRC. Now if only I could find it...

Comment: Isn't depth, by definition, inversely proportional to the elementariness of proofs?

Comment: How do you define the "deapness" of a proof or of a theorem?

Comment: If you read Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds", he specifically structures the whole book around making Stokes' Theorem trivial to prove... does that count?

Comment: @detly I don't know the particular example to which you are referring, but I don't think it counts as "simple" if you tuck away all the hard work in lemma after lemma and use them produce a two-line proof of a big result.

Comment: I am sure this is not what you had in mind, but I am tempted to mention the "elementary" proofs of the Prime Number Theorem due to Erdős and Selberg. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Surprising Generalizations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/surprising-generalizations)

Comment: Why is this closed? Reopen, thank you. Leave reason if you vote to close?

Comment: How about "reopen, please"?!? Also "PLZ reopen" in the title is obnoxious.

Comment: @GM2001: Please stop editing titles to contain messages like "AWESOME" or "
REOPEN !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!...please!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!". This is not the first time you're doing it.

Comment: @GM2001: If you edit this question any more, I will lock it, which will prevent further edits, comments, and answers.

Answer (score 9):

These perhaps aren't particularly deep, but they are the first that come to mind.

1. [Irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ by contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality).
2. [Uncountability of the reals by diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).
3. [Existence of graphs with arbitrarily high girth and chromatic number by the probabilistic method](http://cs.nyu.edu/cs/faculty/spencer/ohiostate/os2.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I think one should not confuse "important with "deep". The facts that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, that there is no surjective map $X\to2^X$, or that there are an infinity of primes, are certainly important or even "fundamental", but their proofs are so simple that one cannot call them "deep". A theorem is "deep" when its proof is really hard and, above all, requires a theory that transcends the realm the problem is formulated in. Consider, e.g., Gauss' theorem about which regular $n$-gons can be constructed with ruler and compass.

Comment: I think the theorem that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational would have met your criterion for depth at the time it was discovered. Imagine that the Greeks saw $\sqrt{2}$ as the length of the diagonal of a unit square (rather than as the positive solution to $x^2=2$). Then to show the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, we need to transcend geometry to go to number theory, where we have available the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: To add on Srivatsan's comment, the proof of $|P(X)|>|X|$ while seemingly trivial nowadays required the development of an entire new field in mathematics. I'd say this qualifies as pretty deep.